# How to get Android Layer chat integration chat conversion Images?

Tags: android, chat, layer

I am integrating my Android app with Layer chat sdk (https://layer.com/).

I am going through the Layer Documentation for implementing the chat, I had succeed, I can able to send, receive the text messages.

My problem is when I am sending an image successfully, but receiver not able to receiving the image

Sending Image code:

```
Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.back_icon);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();    
imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] imageData = stream.toByteArray();
MessagePart messagePart = layerClient.newMessagePart("image/jpeg", imageData);
```

Receiving Image code:

```
{
    List<MessagePart> parts = message.getMessageParts();

  for(MessagePart part : parts) {

     switch (part.getMimeType()) {

        case "text/plain":
            String textMsg = new String(part.getData());
            break;

        case "image/jpeg":
            Bitmap imageMsg = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(part.getData(), 0, part.getData().length);
            break;
    }
}
```

Why is here `part.getData()` value returning `null`?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I am facing exactly the same. Please share the solution

Comment: @user3267567 I didn't solve the problem,Now i am also getting same............

Comment: user3267567 : I found the solution for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

layerClient.setAutoDownloadMimeTypes(Arrays.asList("image/jpeg"));

The Above code will take by default less than **2KB** if the size is exceeds

layerClient.setAutoDownloadSizeThreshold(1024 * 100);

You need to specify this code it will take up to  100kb,Your problem will solve

for more info :  https://developer.layer.com/docs/android/guides#richcontent